# i want to open a 3ds image in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have converted .3ds image to xaml and its like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>


<model name="boy" num_sub_meshes="1" num_materials="10" >

    <material name="c7d648bf_dds" index="0" opacity="1.000000" >
        <ambient r="0.400000" g="0.400000" b="0.400000" a="1.000000" />
        <diffuse r="0.100000" g="0.100000" b="0.100000" a="1.000000" />
        <specular r="0.000000" g="0.000000" b="0.000000" a="1.000000" exp="10.000000" />
    </material>

    <material name="_5bd6bc7_dds" index="1" opacity="1.000000" >
        <ambient r="0.698039" g="0.698039" b="0.698039" a="1.000000" />
        <diffuse r="0.698039" g="0.698039" b="0.698039" a="1.000000" />
        <specular r="1.000000" g="1.000000" b="1.000000" a="1.000000" exp="10.000000" />
    </material>


</model>
```

where do i have to add this xaml code to get a view of 3d image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not xaml. You will have to write code to parse the 3ds file and programmatically create xaml to display something.

You should check out this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63303/Converting-ds-Models-to-XAML-Resources-for-a-WPF, it seems to be what you are after.